# firebase not creating data when user signs for first time

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

*when new user signIn, In firebase Authentication tab it is showing users details.
but not adding the function to firestore.*

*google signIn code:*

```
     Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });

    final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser?.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );

    final UserCredential authResult =
        await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    final user = authResult.user;

    if (authResult.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
      if (user != null) {
        await DbServices().addNewUser(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
      }
    }
    removeLoading();
    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
  removeLoading() {
    return Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}

**this is addNewUser function:**
    Future addNewUser(useruid) async {
        int heartid = await updateHeartId();
        print('updated Heart Id $heartid....................');
        await usersCollection.doc(useruid).set({
          'user name': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName,
          'uid': useruid,
          'heartId': heartid,
          'total hearts': 0,
          'ringed': false,
          'Timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          'profile pic': '',
          'todayRinged': false,
          'ringedDay': DateTime.now().day,
        });
      }
```

*when I looked into it, firebase isn't adding the function addNewUser in firestore.
I don't understand what's happening here.
when I signIn for first time the app crashes saying :*

> 

```
> StateError(Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform
> which does not exist)
```

*why is the addNewUser function not adding to firestore?*

Comment: Have you tried to see if Firebase servers reject the write operation?

Comment: I fixed it. The issue was  adNewUser function was taking some time to complete because of a function updateheartid inside it.

Comment: I put updateheartid function to the last of addNewUser. And it's working fine